# Swap objects in array?

Tags: java, android

I have this array `ColorObject gameGrid[][] = new ColorObject[8][8];` It's a grid of sprite objects of the type ColorObject. Each object draw a circle in different colors.

I'm selecting one of them by comparing the `x` and `y` of the touch input coordinates with the positions of all objects in a loop to get the `x` index and `y` index of the selected object in the array. I then use this index values as `selectedGridPositionX` and `selectedGridPositionY`.

I also get the object like this: 
`selectedColorObject = gameGrid[col][row];`

Finally in a method I'm trying to swap them like this:

```
tempColorObject = gameGrid[selectedGridPositionX + 1][selectedGridPositionY];
gameGrid[selectedGridPositionX + 1][selectedGridPositionY] = selectedColorObject;
gameGrid[selectedGridPositionX][selectedGridPositionY] = tempColorObject;
```

This works almost. On screen they swap, but when I touch them, they show the values from the previously object. What could I have done wrong? I hope my question isn't too unclear?

Comment: try using the array as static

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "touch them"? Something like `gameGrid[col][row].getValue()`?

Comment: Maybe the data is duplicated somewhere, and you update it only at one place.

Comment: @Chechulin I'm doing some calculation to check which objects X and Y position is whitin an area. The error could be there. I'm checking right now

Comment: @zeller When I swap them, I guess the array are updated then!?

Comment: Does ColorObject have fields like `x` or `y`? It should be updated!

Comment: It's working now! Thanks for comments! The reason why it didn't work was an error in the algoritm that detects the touch position with the position of the objects. Thanks! :)